# Python3 add multiple headers in a request

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I want to send a request using these custom 2 Headers:

```
Host: website.com
Origin: anotherwebsite.com
```

Here is my python3 code:

```
headers = [("Host" , "https://website.com",
           ("Origin" , "https://evil.com")]
request = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
```

When executed it shows this error: 
`'list' object has no attribute 'items'` and it refers to this line `request = requests.get(site, headers=headers)`

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a dictionary:

```py
headers = {
    "Host": "https://website.com",
    "Origin": "https://evil.com",
}

request = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
```